# Executor service getting terminated without waiting for the task to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have my executor service like this:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
  Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
  exec.execute(new ConsumerstartUpThread(consumer));
}
```

`ConsumerStartUpThread` implements runnable and it has huge functionality in its run method, which requires calling several other APIs. Now when I run the code in debug mode, the task is getting finished. And when i run it normally the tasks are incomplete, and threads are getting terminated. Is it not that the threads will wait until all the tasks gets finished? Why they are getting terminated without finishing tasks?

Comment: If you explain more about what you mean by "getting terminated", it might help uncover the issue. Is the entire JVM shutting down? Does the ExecutorService shut down? Do threads block or get interrupted or what?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tasks.add(Executors.callable(new ConsumerstartUpThread(new Consumer())));
}
exec.invokeAll(tasks);
exec.shutdown();
```

invokeAll will wait until all tasks terminate (see API). To make it simpler make ConsumerstartUpThread implement Callable instead of Runnable

Comment: No. But my thread is getting suspended even before the task is finished. And if i give exec.awaitTermination(10000,TimeUnit.MILLI_SECONDS) the tasks are getting finished. But i want my threads to finish once the tasks are done only...